# Getting data as a Class Component rather than a Hook

Tags: reactjs

I'm using Auth0, and can grab the data using hooks like so:

`const { user } = useAuth0()`

How can I refactor and get that same data in a Class Component?  I just cannot figure it out or find a good example.  I've tried:

`this.state = { user: useAuth0()}`

But no luck...

Comment: Are you using `'@auth0/auth0-react'`

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have included that.  I have these lines at the top of the file:

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

Answer (score 1):

`auth0-react` provides a HOC `withAuth0` which you can use with class components as mentioned [here](https://auth0.github.io/auth0-react/)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

class Profile extends Component {
  render() {
    // `this.props.auth0` has all the same properties as the `useAuth0` hook
    const { user } = this.props.auth0;
    return <div>Hello {user.name}</div>;
  }
}

export default withAuth0(Profile);
```

Comment: How would you import this then in the higher order component. Doing import {Profile} does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper function component outside class component;

```
const AuthWrapper = (E)=> {
    const WrapperComponent = (props)=> {
        const { user } = useAuth0()
        return <E user={user} {...props} />
    }
    return WrapperComponent;
}
```

Class Component

```
@AuthWrapper
class AuthDemo extends Component {
    render() {
        const { user } = this.props;
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `higher order component` to implements.

more details: [use-with-a-class-component](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react#use-with-a-class-component)